# Calculation in a select statement

Tags: sql

With the following table details, I want to list the Order ID and the total cost of each order.

```
Product (ProductID,ProductDescription, QtyInStock, ReOrderLevel, CostPrice, SellPrice)
Order(OrderNum, OrderDate, DeliveryDate)    
OrderDetails (OrderDetailID, OrderNum, ProductID, Quantity)
```

My stab at it, I have

```
SELECT OrderNumber, sum(SellPrice * Quantity) AS TotalCost
FROM OrderDetail
INNER JOIN Product
ON Product.ProductID = OrderDetail.ProductID
```

How can I show the result of the sum per order number?

Comment: You are missing `group by `OrderNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group the results, using `group by`. Now you are getting the sum over all, and show it on every line.

This code will give the result you expect:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, sum(SellPrice * Quantity) AS TotalCost
FROM OrderDetail
INNER JOIN Product
ON Product.ProductID = OrderDetail.ProductID
group by OrderNumber
```